# Set column position in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm truying to build a column  chart where 1 series overlaps the other (2) series.
I've attached a picture for better understanding.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: The chart in the screenshot was created using "pointWidth" and "groupPadding" - but this only works for "static" chart that can not be resized. Resizing the shown chart will break the layout...

Comment: You will get more help if you post some code and a jsfiddle showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is possible, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/rLskooht/

- set: grouping: false, zIndex: (e.g.) 10, pointPadding: 0.3 for on top series
- first series should the one will be on top

Code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['cat1', 'cat2']
    },
    series: [{
        grouping: false,
        data: [70, 50],
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        zIndex: 10
    },{
        data: [123, 100]        
    },{
        data: [100, 90]        
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is a way to do this with custom positioning per bar, which future users may need if this simple but elegant solution above is insifficient.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement

Code:

Note the percentage based `pointPosition` and `pointPadding` options.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Seattle HQ',
                'San Francisco',
                'Tokyo'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit (millions)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Employees',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
            data: [150, 73, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [140, 90, 40],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit',
            color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
            data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
            data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
});
```